# Javascript: location.replace and CSS-classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to translate the following HTML into a Javascript function:

```
<a class='example' href="../content/flash.html">Click Me</a>
```

Basically, I want to duplicate the effect of  clicking the link via JS.

```
function doStuff()
        {
            location.replace('../content/ajax.html');
        }
```

The above code simply redirects to ajax.html.

How can I activate the CSS-class 'example' via Javascript when redirecting?

The reason I want to do this: the CSS-class 'example' shows the content of ajax.html inside a lightbox ([Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to be exact).

Comment: There is no such thing as "a CSS class". Do you mean "A CSS rule-set with a class selector"? "An HTML element that is a member of a particular (HTML) class"? Something else?

Comment: What does "activate" mean in this context? In CSS terms, if something is active, then it is having the mouse button depressed while being pointed at, or a trigger key depressed while it has the focus, but that doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Calling `location.replace` won't have the same effect as clicking the link. It replaces the current page in the history. You'd want `location.href = something` for that.

Comment: The question is vague. Please describe what you want to happen in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to achieve results like this is to get into jQuery, specifically its `click()` handler and ajax `load()` function:

HTML

```
<div id="contentArea"></div>
<a class="example" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {

    $('a.example').click(function () { 
        $('#contentArea').load('../content/flash.html');   
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Whew. This looks way more elegant than my gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda confused as well, but here's a guess.

You could give the  an id:

```
<a id='clickMe' class='example' href="../content/flash.html">Click Me</a>
```

And in js:

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").className = "example";
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you looking for something like this

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').className = 'myRedDivClass';
```

try using jquery will make your life easy

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

I do hope I undesrtood the question, since... Well, it's a bit odd. Here goes ~
**EDIT**: I wrote "I didn't hope I understood the question. I meant *do*. LOL

If you have more than just one `.example` class then you have to use `getElementsByClassName();`, but not all browsers support that. If you however only have one element, then I suggest assigning it an ID, and then select that element by using `getElementById();`.

A solution for `getElementsByClassName();`not being supported in all browsers would be:

```
function getElementsByClassName(classname) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    } else {
        return (function (classn, document) {
            var classElements = [],
                e = document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
                len = e.length,
                pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classn + "(\\s|$)"),
                i, k;

            for (i = 0, k = 0; i<len; i++) {
                if (pattern.test(e[i].className)) {
                    classElements[k] = e[i];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            return classElements;
        })(classname, document);
    }
}
```

---

### The linking Part

So, I think the best way of doing that is using `addEventListener();` however, that's my personal opinion, and you might find someone else's who you think is more suitable for what you need it.

```
function doStuff() {
    location.replace('../content/ajax.html');
}

var es = getElementsByClassName('example'),
    len = e.length;

for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
    es[i].addEventListener("click", doStuff, false);
}
```

xoxo

PS: I didn't verify this, so if something's wrong someone edit it or let me know in the comments!